# How to match Contours to detect ASCII of letter on Image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, contour

We are working on implementing an OCR on OpenCv. We have gained the contours from our images. Now the part we are stuck on is how can we use these contours to recognize the characters that are now showing on our contour image?

What is to be used? I mean basically how do we use the information gained from the contours to  our benefit?

Comment: So you're asking how to write the OCR part of OCR? And you're not showing any code? What sort of answer do you expect, really?

Comment: Just a general direction that's all.

Comment: Did you create a solution for this problem of doing ocr from the contour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use various properties of contours for matching, like their bounding boxes (`cvBoundingRect`) or ellipses (`cvFitEllipse2`), their moments (`cvContourMoments`), their convexity (`cvCheckContourConvexity`, `cvConvexHull2`). `

`cvMatchShapes` calculates Hu moments for comparison. You can also create pairwise geometrical histograms (`cvCalcPGH`).

You may check Gary Bradski's and Adrian Kaehler's Learning OpenCV for details.

Comment: @Prometheus87: for starters, cvMatchShapes should work. Gather a template image for each character class. Then see which of these the detected contour matches with the most. OCR is rather complex. Doing a search on `google scholar` would give you the right theoretical backing for more refined ways.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at tesseract to learn a bit more about OCR implementation :)
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout